# How should we flag questions that do not actually ask a question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

How should we close or flag a question that clearly does not actually contain a question?  For example, I have seen several "questions" where the asker is simply wanting someone to explain a concept, or provide a tutorial.

The closest option I can think of is `Off Topic -> Asking for recommendation` flag, but that doesn't seem to fit in my mind.

Comment: Providing a tutorial is too broad (or asking for an off-site resource, both will work). Explaining a concept is too vague to judge and isn't by definition closeable. If the concept can be answered in a few paragraphs it is OK. So, it depends.

Answer (score 3):

"Too broad" fits these cases well.

Comment: If the *Explain a concept* question is narrow scoped I don't see why it should be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 2):

> How should we close or flag a question that clearly does not actually contain a question?

You can flag them as **Too broad** or **unclear what you're asking**

If the question is like `write code for me` or `do home work for me` or `question with zero attemtpt` than you can flag them as **Too broad**

If the Questions written in non-English should be closed as **unclear what you're asking.**

if the user failed to explain concept than you can flag as  **unclear what you're asking.**